# Multiplicar un porcentaje en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Me podrían decir si en SQL Server 2012 se puede multiplicar un porcentaje?
Ejemplo:

2084318.77378358 * 0.0483% = 1006.725967737469

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
SELECT VALOR * 0.0483 FROM AR_TABLA WHERE NOMBRE = 'F58'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O sea, la forma de multiplicar por "un porcentaje" es hacer tu multiplicación y dividir por 100:

```
SELECT Valor*0.0483/100
FROM dbo.AR_TABLA
WHERE NOMBRE = 'F58';
```